# Creating user without username (or with auto-generated username)

Tags: python, django

I want to create a registration page that doesn't ask for an username, since i'm not planning on using it (i only need email and password).

However, i'm not sure how to tell django that username is not mandatory.

I'm having trouble registering users because they all get the same username (blank).

My user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

My form for registering:

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta():
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'departments', 'password1', 'password2')
        model = get_user_model()
```

The view:

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('loginPage')
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
```

What should i change in order to tell django to ignore the username field for the User model?

Is a random auto-generated username a good idea to avoid this problem? If yes, how do i code it?

@Shahzeb Qureshi, i tried this:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta():
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'departments', 'password1', 'password2')
        model = get_user_model()
        labels = {
            'username':gettext_lazy('E-mail'),
        }
```

Comment: What I first thought when reading this question is to prepare some kind of function that You would pass to the User model itself which would be ran everytime a new user is created - Generating random username at the same time. But this function would also have to check if there's no current user with this handle in the database (random doesn't excluce the possiblity of duplicate). Second thing is that I am pretty sure it is possible to achieve what You're trying to do. That would probably mean adjusting the existing User model itself excluding username field from it.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be that you enter the email address in your username field instead of leaving it blank.

Comment: Ok that seems good.. Can i ask how exactly do you code that? It's my first project and from what i read from the documentation i think what you mean is using a different label for username (e-mail label).. is it?
However that way i lose the default validators for the email field (for example, if someone forgets to use "@" symbol..). Check my edit please

Comment: from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 
 user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST.get('email'),
                                 email=request.POST.get('email'),
                                 password=request.POST.get('passowrd'))

Comment: In the above code the email fetched from your post request is passed to the email field as well as the username field which serves the purpose

Answer (score -1):

Just generate the username from email use the code is given below

```
    email = 'punnapavankumar9@gmail.com'
    username = email.split('@')[0]
```

Comment: In this scenario if the same ID is created with a different email provider such as yahoo or Outlook then it will throw a username already exists error

Comment: In this case you can generate a serial number for every user. And for those not having username you can enter the serial number after the above code email.split() function. For validating email you can use "if '@' in email" method